# Fusion drive benefits for Boot Camp?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, imac

I've got a late-2015 Retina iMac with Fusion drive. From what I understand, but want to confirm, is that there is no real benefit for Boot Camp as the partition is completely on the HDD side, so the speed in Boot Camp is considerably slower than if it had SSD access.

How can I confirm this or even see the two 'sides' of my Fusion Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Camp Assistant partitions the HDD so that Windows can be installed. Windows does not support Core Storage, hence the partition is solely on the HDD.

> Do Macs that have a Fusion Drive support Boot Camp?
>   Yes. Boot Camp Assistant creates the Windows partition on the disk drive instead of the flash drive (SSD).

<sup>Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201456</sup>

Speaking of Core Storage, this is what is used to make your two disks appear as one logical volume. You can't see the individual drives' content separately. For more information, see [Core Storage Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Storage) or search "Core Storage".